# How to prevent or avoid Cache in Angular 2 + Applications?

Tags: angular, pdf, angular6, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a situation where i send parameters to an API which in turn generates dynamic pdf & API sends me the path of newly generated file. When i open the file in browser it shows newly generated file, but In my DOM I still see the old file untill & unless i close the browser & hit the API Again. I am previewing the generated pdf file as follows :

TS PART :

```
this.http.postMethod("report/auditAdmin", data).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.toolbar = "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0";
        this.pdfSrc = res.filepath + this.toolbar;
        this.Url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfSrc);
      });
```

HTML PART :

```
<object [data]="Url" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1000px"></object>
```

Comment: Is the URL always the same or are they different?

Comment: always on same host

Comment: So it's different? If so, then caching is not the problem and you need to create a new `object` element. If it's the you can solve the problem by adding a random parameter to it.

Comment: Yes i thought of adding random parameter but that will create multiple pdf & i want to replace the pdf every time the user  comes from his ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the API Cache or Angular, The issue is with the object control.
When we try to load the data like pdf file or any other external content object sends a **get request** to show the content (get request can be viewd in browser's network tab).

So the simple solution is append querystring to your pdf path.

```
this.http.postMethod("report/auditAdmin", data).subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.toolbar = "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0";
            let ramdom = Math.random();
            this.pdfSrc = res.filepath + "?v=" + random + this.toolbar;
            this.Url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfSrc);
          });
```

Now whenever your object tries make a get request to pdf file each request will be fresh because of querystring and hence data will not get loaded from cache.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent/avoid cache in Angular 2+ version you can achieve by overriding the RequestOptions.

**Step 1** : Create Custom RequestOptions.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    headers = new Headers({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'
    });
}
```

**Step 2** Provide in Root `AppModule.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: CustomRequestOptions }
    ]
})
```

Hope above solution will solve your problem!.